# How to execute completition handler in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

Hi stackoverflow community

I have the following code from github project: 
https://github.com/hybrdthry911/ELStripe which has been covered here:
[Store credit card using Stripe + Parse with cloud code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338983/store-credit-card-using-stripe-parse-with-cloud-code)

```
    -(void)createCardFromToken:(NSString *)tokenId customerId:(NSString *)customerId completionHandler:(ELCardCompletionBlock)handler
    {
    [ELStripe executeStripeCloudCodeWithMethod:@"POST" 
        //I use post here because we are creating a card. POST would also be used for updating a customer/card or refunding a charge for example
        prefix:@"customers" //If you look at the documentation and the example URL I use "customers" here as the prefix
        suffix:customerId //The customerID is the suffix, this will be the customer you are going to add the card to
        postfix:@"cards" //I believe this is "sources" now
        secondPostfix:nil //Not needed for this URL
        parameters:@{
            @"card":tokenId  //Only parameter is a tokenId, and I wrap this inside an NSDictionary
        }
        completionHandler:^(id jsonObject, NSError *error) {
                                 if (error)
                                 {
                                     //Handle the error code here

                                     handler(nil,error); //rejectError 
                                     return;
                                 }
                                 //If no error stripe returns a dictionary containing the card information. You can use this information to create a card object if so desired.
                                 handler([ELCard cardFromDictionary:jsonObject],error);
                             }];
    }
```

My problem is now that I as a n00b in Objective-C, have no idea how this method can be used:

```
[self createCardFromToken:<#(NSString *)#> customerId:<#(NSString *)#> completionHandler:<#^(ELCard *card, NSError *error)handler#>];
```

Could anyone point me in the direction what I have to put in after: completionHandler?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Question is not clear. Please edit the question.

Comment: Since there are already answers to this question, please consider accepting the one that helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `completionHandler` should be a block. You can read more about them here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Easiest way is to just hit Enter when the `completionHandler` placeholder is highlighted while you are writing the method using autocomplete. It will automatically write the block skeleton for you. If you have to do it manually, it should look like this:

```
[self createCardFromToken:@"token value" customerId:@"customer ID" completionHandler:^(ELCard *card, NSError *error) {
    // your custom code that uses card and error values
}];
```

Comment: +1 for the "hit enter when placeholder is highlighted" tip. This helped me a lot in getting used to the (at first foreign and intimidating) Swift syntax for closures.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how to call this method.

```
[self createCardFromToken:@"a token string" customerId:@"a customer id string" completionHandler:^(ELCard *card, NSError *error){
        // here goes code you want to execute when the completion handler gets called
}];
```